# Calculate page rank

Tags: algorithm, search-engine, pagerank

I'm learning PageRank algorithm and from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PageRank), it gives the following formula:

[image]

From the formula, the page rank is calculated from the ranks of pages linking to it. Also, they give a simple example of four nodes A,B,C,D. Initially, each node has a page rank of 0.25. Therefore, if nodes B,C,D link to node A and there are no other links, `PR(A) = 0.15 + 0.85*(0.25 + 0.25 + 0.25) = 0.7875` and `PR(B) = PR(C) = PR(D) = 0.15`. But the sum of page ranks is not equal to 1 which is the sum of ranks at the inital step. Am I wrong for this calculation?

I've read [another tutorial](http://www.pagerank.dk/Pagerank-sheet/Spreadsheet-simple.htm), and in their calculation, the sum of ranks is always the same. Can anyone explain me where I'm wrong? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The formula that keeps the sum equal to 1 is `(1 - d) / N + d * (...)`, not the one in your post (it's okay that the sum is not one with your formula). The Wikipedia article is clear about it:

> The damping factor adjusts the derived value downward. The original
>   paper, however, gave the following formula, which has led to some
>   confusion:
>
> ... (your formula goes here)
>
> The difference between them is that the PageRank values in the
>   first formula sum to one, while in the second formula each PageRank is
>   multiplied by N and the sum becomes N.

Comment: Yes, I see. But the point is that the sum (1 or whatever) of page ranks should not be changed over iterations. In the tutorial I mention, the sum is always equal to 5.